# VertX SqlClientApi/SqlConnection Question

Tags: vert.x

The documentation says

> The JDBC Client API created in Vert.x 3 is now deprecated and instead the new SQL Client API should be used. It will remain supported for the life time of Vert.x 4 to allow applications to be migrated to the new SQL Client API.

It seems that this class works in an Autocommit-Mode. If I have several database calls within one Service, how should this work with transaction-consistency? Is it planned, that the "commit", "rollback" will also be available as it is in SQLConnection?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at Javadocs of the new client transaction APIs in  https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/sqlclient/Pool.html#withTransaction-java.util.function.Function-, the JDBCClient will execute the block starting with disabling auto-commit mode and ending with a commit or rollback execution.

Comment: Thx, I overlooked them